# owl carousel custom navigation trigger parent event

Tags: jquery

I am using Owl Carousel, with synced sliders.
I am using a custom navigation which triggers the owl-next function.

My problem is, that triggering the "next" slide in the bottom slide is working, but not the second button, which should trigger the parent slider.

My code so far:

```
$(".konfig-slide-top").owlCarousel({
        navigation: false,
        pagination: false,
        slideSpeed: 1000,
        paginationSpeed: 500,
        paginationNumbers: false,
        singleItem: true,
        autoPlay: false,
        autoHeight:false,
        animateIn: 'slideIn',
        animateOut: 'slideOut',
        afterAction : syncPositionnew,
        responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
        afterMove: afterActionnew
    });

var owl = $(".konfig-slide-inner");

    owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        pagination: false,
        navigation: false,

        slideSpeed: 800,
        paginationSpeed: 700,
        animateIn: 'slideIn',
        animateOut: 'slideOut',
        autoHeight: true,
        responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
        mouseDrag: false,
        loop: false,
        afterInit : function(el){
        el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("syncednew2");
        }
    });

//slide inner slider        
    $('.next-inner').click(function() {
        owl.trigger('owl.next');
    });

    // slide parent slider
    $('.next-top').click(function() {
        var top = $(".konfig-slide-top").find('owl-controls');
        top.trigger('owl.next');
    });
```

The other possible solution for the parent slider was:

```
var top = $(".konfig-slide-top");

    // slide parent slider
    $('.next-top').click(function() {
        top.trigger('owl.next');
    });
```

I seem to miss something. Does anyone know what?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. Well it seems so.

```
var top = $(".konfig-slide-top");

    // slide parent slider
    $('.next-top').click(function() {
        top.trigger('owl.next');
        return false;
    });
```

Adding return false; made the code work.
But I don't quite understand why. :/ Can anyone explain it to me?